# App that quickly analyzes waveforms and displays tones

Tags: audio, pc, tone, waveform, program

I used to have a light program on my PC that would let you record a short audio file and would display useful information such as note length and tone. It was an extremely helpful tool for experimenting and doodling.
The thing is, I don't have access to it anymore, I forgot the name and I can't find it. Anyone know what I'm talking about?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an audio to midi converter. By analysing the audio file, you can retrieve pitch and duration information which coincidentally is what you require to generate midi note-on and note-off messages.

[Something like this?](https://www.widisoft.com/english/widi-audio-to-midi-vst.html)

Answer (score 1):

ableton has a drag n drop feature that allows you to place a wave or mp3 in a midi track and get kind've interpretation of what the melody and harmony is, though you may have to use your sensibilies to extract the parts you want